# Implicit resolution of dependent types in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, dependent-type, scala-implicits

Consider the following piece of code:

```
trait Foo {
  type T
  def value: T
}

object Foo {
  def apply[A](v: A): Foo = new Foo {
    override type T = A
    override def value = v
  }
}

trait Decode[A] {
  def apply(x: A): String
}

object Decode {
  def apply[A](f: A => String): Decode[A] = new Decode[A] {
    override def apply(x: A) = f(x)
  }

  implicit val decodeStr: Decode[String] = Decode(identity)
}

class Sandbox {
  def decodeFoo(foo: Foo)(implicit decoder: Decode[foo.T]): String =
    decoder(foo.value)

  val foo = Foo("hello")
  println(decodeFoo(foo))
}
```

The above code should work fine and print `hello` but instead it fails to compile:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter decoder: Decode[Sandbox.this.foo.T]
[error]   println(decodeFoo(foo))
```

Even when I **explicitly** pass in the implicit param:

```
println(decodeFoo(foo = foo)(decoder = Decode.decodeStr))
```

I still get this error now:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Decode[String]
[error]  required: Decode[Sandbox.this.foo.T]
[error]   println(decodeFoo(foo = foo)(decoder = Decode.decodeStr))
[error]                                                 ^
```

Ofcourse, I can make `Foo` a `Foo[T]` and define decoders for it but that's not the point of this question - I want to understand why the above code fails to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem exists here:

```
object Foo {
  def apply[A](v: A): Foo = new Foo {
    override type T = A
    override def value = v
  }
}
```

There, you've established that you will return a `Foo` but not, specifically, which `Foo`. Hence, that function only knows that it can return a `Foo` for any type `T`. You need an `Aux` pattern to recapture the type which is lost when establishing your new `Foo` (yes, yes...)

```
object Foo {
  type Aux[A] = Foo{ type T = A }

  def apply[A](v: A): Aux[A] = new Foo {
    type T = A
    def value = v
  }
}
```

which then says that for a given `A` produce the `Foo` which has it's `T` dependent type set to `A`.

Comment: Or directly `def apply[A](v: A): Foo { type T = A } = new Foo { ... }`.